# React Native or Xcode: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH

Tags: xcode, react-native, command-line

```
xcrun: error: sh -c '/Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk /Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk -find instruments 2> /dev/null' failed with exit code 17664: (null) (errno=No such file or directory)
xcrun: error: unable to find utility "instruments", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

Posting this because on my M1 in Monterrey Beta I spent some time slamming my head against the wall... I found the fix though

Answer (score 10):

```
sudo xcode-select -r
```

I had to run the reset command line tools command, a simple solution for something I somehow messed up.

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue with react-native when running `react-native run ios`.

I just **renamed my Xcode** app in the application's directory:

`Xcode-13.1.0.app --> Xcode.app`